# Will repackaging a ship remove all of its upgrades?

Tags: eve-online

I have a ship, capable of transporting 2-3 other ships in its cargo hold. If I wanted to transport some of my other ships to another station, I could repackage these ships, put them into the cargo hold of the bigger ship, and then set out to the new station.

The ships I would be repackaging all have a variety of weapons and rigs on them. If I repackage these ships, what will happen to all of these items?

Obviously I could remove the weapons and other stuff to test, but rigs can't be removed without destroying them so I am a bit reluctant to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, repackaging will destroy your rigs, and automatically strip all the leftover fitted mods. (Non-rigs modules are not destroyed.)

There is no way to repackage a ship without losing the rigs. The only way to transport them is in a carrier or in the ship bay of an Orca.

Comment: Or by flying it there, then either flying your pod back or buying a cheap shuttle.

Comment: Or by 'joining' the goons and letting them take care of it.